# Sys_schema in MySQL Workbench missing after clean reinstallation

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've installed MySQL Workbench on my Macbook, but I have some problems with running scripts and creating databases, so I had to reinstall it. After reinstalling this Workbench, I found out that I am missing sys_schema in my schemas, which should be default there.

Do you know maybe how to install it there, or add it there? Cause now, I can't do anything. If I'm trying to run script, or something it's not working.

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: MySQL workbench is just a GUI tool, it only shows what's available on a MySQL server. Its installation or deinstallation has nothing to do with what's available on the MySQL server. sys schema is available from MySQL v5.7.7. What's your MySQL version? Also, pls provide and accurate and detailed description of the error. We cannot help to fix "something is not working" type of questions. In its current format your question does not make sense and it is unanswerable.

Comment: @Shadow Thanks, for your answer. I just figure it out what was the problem. When I looked on your answer and saw MySQL version I went to check it and I've noticed that I don't have MySQL installed, because I forgot that I was trying to uninstall it through terminal with workbench.

I installed it again and also workbench and now I can see sys_schema there, so it should work properly. Also thanks for advice how to write questions and all those details.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue that the schema is still there but the user that you use to connect to MySQL in Workbench lacks the rights to see it.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-schema.html